# Join a table only where there is a count in the subquery

Tags: php, sql-server, join

I'm making a search engine in which a page visitor can search for music artists based on 4 different attributes which the artists will have a rating of from 0- 100 and by entering the minimum value of a specified attribute, the visitor can view the list of artists with ratings greater than or equal to the desired value. After the query I have the fetch array and foreach statement already set but I am having trouble with the query.

I've tried the following query statement. It's one cohesive statement:

```
SELECT users.username, databaseimage.profile 
// users.username is artists username
// databaseimage is table where profile pic is stored

FROM users 
JOIN databaseimage ON users.id = databaseimage.user_id 
JOIN attributes ON users.id = attributes.userid 
// user.id, database.user_id, and attribute.userid all correspond to the id of a specified artist

// attributes is table where attributes are stored
```

**The above gets me all the data that I need. Below is the part I need help with.** I want to narrow the data down such that only the data corresponding to artists with attribute ratings (as attr) greater than $selectnumber (Number specified by the visitor) is in the the result array. This what I have tried.

```
WHERE attribute.userid 
HAVING COUNT() IN (
  SELECT userid, ($attribute DIV TotalRatingEntries) as attr 
  FROM attributes 
  WHERE attr >= '$selectnumber'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A far as I understand data structure I can propose the query below:

```
SELECT 
    users.username, 
    databaseimage.profile
FROM 
    users 
    JOIN databaseimage ON users.id = databaseimage.user_id 
    JOIN attributes ON users.id = attributes.userid
WHERE 
    attribute.userid IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            userid
        FROM 
            attributes  
        group by
            userid,TotalRatingEntries
        having
            sum(attribute)/TotalRatingEntries >= '$selectnumber'
    )
```

Please provide more details about these 3 tables, maybe I misunderstood something.